# Google link when searching an user's questions is not supported

Tags: bug, status-completed, google, search

When one searches for an user's questions when there are no results, e.g. like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1234+foobar

, then a Google search is offered. However, this Google search gives an error:

```
user:1234 was dropped from your search because it is not supported for
this type of search.
```

I guess this is because Google has reserved `key:value` keywords for use in like `site:somewebsite.com`.

Anyway, I honestly think it would be more user-friendly if either a Google search link in this case is removed, or that the `user:1234` part is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the next build, if the search includes any advanced search options (`option:value` format), we'll omit the google search link...which we agree wouldn't be very useful in these narrow search situations anyway.